# error: Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start. during deployment of Spring-MVC project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I was trying to deploy one Spring-MVC

[image]

project on tomcat server. At first trial, it deployed successfully but on second trial it is showing me a prompt with the detail "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start."

[image]

Please help me out.

Comment: please edit your question. share your error in text format not image

Comment: Thank you, Ved Prakash, for your advice. As I am new here. I will take care of it.

Comment: The thing is that I am done with deleting ".snap" file but the solution is not working

Answer (score 0):

issue occuring in mapping of servlet into xml file, error is you are using uknown servlet into mapping, so youe need to use proper servlet name with the full package path into mapping. you can find sample below

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ManagerAccess</servlet-name>  // access name
    <servlet-class>com.securecloud.services.ManagerServices</servlet-class> //servlet with full path
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ManagerAccess</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ManagerUtilities</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .snap file located in the directory

```
<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
```

After deleting this file, try restarting eclipse and then start tomcat